# Draggable Element Disappears After Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm trying to use the draggable/sortable effect to add a new element to a list and then open a dialog window asking for a name for it. What happens though is after the dialog closes the newly created element disappears.

```
$(function() {
  $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
    revert: true
  });
  $( "#draggable" ).draggable({
    connectToSortable: "#sortable",
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid",
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      $("#dialog").dialog('open');
    }
  });
  $( "ul, li" ).disableSelection();
});
$(function() {
  $("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 150,
    width: 200,
    modal: true
  });
});
function changeTitle() {
  var boxText = $("#newsTitle").val();
  $(".ui-draggable").text(boxText);
  $(".ui-state-default").removeClass('ui-draggable');
}
```

I think I've narrowed it down to having something do with when the dialog returns. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show working example..may be on jsfiddle.net

Comment: use document.ready() - define your functions outside of this and then call them as callbacks. However your submit dialog is set up, your code thinks that it is going to an external page so it calls everything again, basically refreshing